# iMac display RGB values

Tags: imac, display

Why does the iMac display show non-zero values for blue and green pixels for a .png image whose blue and green color planes are zero?  I used the digital color meter to show the non-zero values for the blue and green pixels and I confirmed that the .png file has zero values in the blue and green color planes by using python scripts to inspect the array values.

Answer (score 1):

You might check the iMac's monitor calibration settings.

> System Preferences > Displays > Color > Calibrate...

or choose one of the other Display profiles. Which Digital Colour Meter are you using?  It probably must be also calibrated in sync with the above setting...

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question.  
I used the Digital Color Meter utility that came with osx 10.10.1.  I did look at the different color maps and switching maps changes the values reported by the DCM but the BG pixels are still active. I calibrated my display and I also changed my displays map to RGB to match the .png file but the GB pixels remain active.  I confirm that these pixels are active using a magnifying optical system to view the pixel visually.